# Translating from Matlab to C a function

Tags: c, matlab, opencv, fft

I am translating a funciton from Matlab to C. I have a problem with just some lines with Fourier Transform. This is the code, the commented lines are in Matlab and That's what I need to translate.

```
   Mat logGabor(Mat imfft,int *sz2filt_r,int *sz2filt_c,double r_o, double theta_o,double sigma_theta,double **radius,double **theta,int cols,int rows,double sigma_r,int *padSize);
     Mat rpad;
     int k=*padSize;
     int rs=*sz2filt_r;
     int cs=*sz2filt_c;
   double x[rs-(2*k)],y[cs-(2*k)],sintheta[rows][cols],costheta[rows][cols];
   double ds[rows][cols],dc[rows][cols],divis[rows][cols],divis2[rows][cols];

   double filter[rows][cols],dalpha[rows][cols],spread[rows][cols];
   double div=(PI)/180.0;

  for(int a=0; a<rows; a++){

  for(int b=0; b<cols; b++){

  theta[a][b]=theta[a][b]*div;

  sintheta[a][b]=sin(theta[a][b]);

  costheta[a][b]=cos(theta[a][b]);

  ds[a][b] = (sintheta[a][b] * cos(theta_o) - costheta[a][b] * sin(theta_o))*div;
  dc[a][b] = (costheta[a][b] * cos(theta_o) + sintheta[a][b] * sin(theta_o))*div;
  dalpha[a][b] = abs(atan2(ds[a][b],dc[a][b]));
  divis[a][b] = -(dalpha[a][b]*dalpha[a][b])/(2*(sigma_theta*sigma_theta));
  spread[a][b]= exp(divis[a][b]);
  divis2[a][b]= -(log((radius[a][b]/r_o) * (radius[a][b]/r_o))/(2*log(sigma_r*sigma_r)));
  filter[a][b]= exp(divis2[a][b]);
  filter[a][b]=filter[a][b]*spread[a][b];
  //  filter = fftshift(filter);

  //  rpad = ifft2(imfft.*filter);
  }
      }

 for(int i=1+k;i<=rs-k;i++)
    x[i]= i;

 for(int i=1+k;i<=cs-k;i++)
      y[i]= i;

  //  rpad=rpad(x,y);  delete x & y from rpad

    return rpad;
    }
```

Comment: You might  want to look at [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html)(pronounced "sigh-pie", although I prefer "skippy" :-) which implements both fftshift and ifft (although NOT ifft2).

Comment: Do u know how functions I have to use for the shift?

Answer (score -3):

Or if you want to code the FFT yourslef, look into MATLABS's fft code and translate it line by line.

Comment: matlab FFT is a built in function. the best he can do is look online for someone who has already done it or use matlab coder to make procedural code of the matlab FFT function.